# Handling form input in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like user to submit a URL as form input (e.g: "http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json") and read the content from the submitted URL.

I'm not sure if my current approach is correct. What should i put in the URL field below?

```
var options = {
    url: '....',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any node frameworks like `Express` or `Koa`?

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know how to get the `url` param  in express?

Comment: see express routing https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: In that case if your form/app makes a `POST` you should be able to hook onto it with `app.post('/formUrl', () => ...)` in your server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (I guess this is what you want):

I suggest using `request-promise` package

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
// post router
app.post('/readUrl', async (req, res) => {
  const uri = req.body.url // http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json

  const options = {
    uri,
    headers: {
      // maybe set some headers to accept other formats of response
    },
    // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
    json: true
  };

  const data = await rp(options);
  // data is json
  res.json(data);
})
```

Comment: @ naga - elixir - jar thanks! Can you share how this can be done in nodejs without the framework? Here's how i set up node server: https://codepen.io/sofie97/pen/axoRbx?editors=1010

Comment: what do you mean by *without the framework*? without `request-promise` package?

Comment: without using expressjs

Comment: honestly, that's too much work. Why not let `express` do the heavy lifting? Anyway let me try

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have the Express logic loaded. IMO, if you have express already working, create a post route that the user can hit:

```
app.post("/form",(req,res)=>{
    //See the request body here.
    console.log(req.body)
);
```

You would then make your AJAX call with the URL you have above. It is worth noting that you will need a body parser on your server.js file.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The plugin allows easier parsing on the server side from the client.

Comment: May i ask how do I pass the URL form variable to express? ```<input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url"/>``` should I use ```app.post("/url",(req,res)=>{```  @Justin Rice

Comment: If this input is part of a form, you can attach the action and method parameters to the form. If you just have inputs, you can reference its value and send the value as the data attribute within the AJAX request. The data will show up in the req object within express, given the paths are identical.